# When declaring CSS variables, why is using single hyphens standard practice?

Tags: css, sass, syntax, css-variables

I'm creating a design system and working through how I want to structure my CSS variables. Many systems I've seen tend to only use single hyphens to describe the hierarchy of the variable. For example:

```
.Button {
  background: var(--color-btn-bg);
  color: var(--color-btn-text);
}
```

My question is: Is there any reason to avoid using other formats such as double underscores or double hyphens (`__`, `--`)? Similar to BEM, I think this could be an interesting way to indicate the intended usage of a variable. For example, you might use something like `var(--color-btn__text--hover)` to indicate that the color is intended to be used as the text color on a button that is in a hover state.

```
.Button {
  background: var(--color-btn__bg);
  border: 1px solid var(--color-btn__border);
  color: var(--color-btn__text);

  &:hover {
    background: var(--color-btn__bg--hover);
    color: var(--color-btn__text--hover);
    border: 1px solid var(--color-btn__border--hover);
  }
}
```

It works perfectly fine in my local testing, but curious if there are any other considerations to keep in mind?

Comment: @BenjaminHargett As you have discovered you can use underscores and dashes just fine; single, double, doesn't matter. The reason that most use just single dashes is to keep it nice and simple, at least that's the reason I have when I write such variables. But be aware that [there actually are issues](https://pyronaur.com/dashes-and-underscores-in-sass-scss/) in SASS/SCSS regarding underscores and dashes (for historical reasons as far as I know) in SASS variable names. So if you mix css custom properties and SASS variables this might cause some confusion. I upvoted, imo it's a valid question.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the article and explanation!